# Excel vba Levenshtein Algorithmn

Tags: .net

I have created a Userform with Excel. I have 2 linked comboboxes and about 10 textboxes. After entering a name in a textbox, I can search the whole Excel sheet. The other textboxes will be filled automatically with the information belonging to the row. Is it possible to start the search by entering only the half of the name? I mean when I just enter `"mill"` instead of `"miller"`, can Excel show me any results? Is it possible with VBA? I have heard it should work with a Levenshtein Algorithmn, but i dont know how to write it with vba. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do i have to write mill in the code? I have 1000 names

Answer (score 0):

Excel's `Range` object has an `AutoComplete()` method, if that's what you're looking for. For example, if you had a list of names in column `A`, starting in row 2, you could use the following VBA code to find the first match:

```vb
Dim strMatch As String
strMatch = Range("A2").AutoComplete("mill")

If Len(strMatch) > 0 Then
    Debug.Print "First match found = " & strMatch
Else
    Debug.Print "No matches found"
End If
```